# Is there any evidence of alternate-reality Time Lords?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, parallel-universe

In his answer to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16394/51226) question, Thaddeus states that we have never seen any evidence of Time Lords from alternate dimensions.

While I trust Thaddeus's judgement, the answer is from 2012. Additionally, the *Doctor Who* franchise is a mighty and messy beast.

Is there any evidence of Time Lords from other dimensions in any official *Doctor Who* work? [Pocket Universes](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pocket_universe) and the like don't count.

Comment: I assume the Meta-Crisis Doctor getting shunted off into an alternate universe doesn't count?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Wasn't he human?

Comment: @RogueJedi Only half

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

- In the TV episode [*Turn Left*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_Left_(Doctor_Who)) (Series 4 episode 11), Donna enters a parallel universe in which **the Doctor** also exists, although he is killed during the events of the parallel universe's version of the episode *The Runaway Bride*.
- In the prose novel [*Timewyrm: Revelation*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Timewyrm:_Revelation), a version of **the Doctor** in an alternate universe becomes the President of the Republic of Great Britain; see [this page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Doctor_(Inferno_Earth)) about him.
- In the prose novel [*The Face of the Enemy*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Face_of_the_Enemy), **the Master** travels to an alternate universe and finds a version of himself (Koschei) there.
- In the comic story [*who's Who?*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Who%27s_Who%3F), **the Doctor** again exists in an alternate universe:

  > Sarah Jane distracts the Doctor while he repairs the TARDIS. This causes the pair to be transported to an alternate Earth where their counterparts are dangerous criminals!

There's also a theory that Peter Cushing's version of the Doctor, from the 1960s [*Dr. Who*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Who_(Dalek_films)) films, is the same person in an alternate universe, but I don't believe this has ever been canonically or even semi-canonically confirmed.

Comment: Well, technically, all of Gallifrey was in a pocket dimension between The Day of the Doctor and whenever Missy showed up. Also, all of the TARDISes in the House dimension (The Doctor's Wife).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The OP said pocket universes don't count. And IIRC the Time Lords who came to the House dimension were originally from our universe?

Comment: Very well. Classic Who. [Inferno](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Inferno_(TV_story)). The alternate Doctor is ruling Earth (at least according to the novel) after his trial in War Games.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch From the page you link to: "*The Doctor is the only individual in this story to not have a counterpart in the parallel universe. Although it was later confirmed that the Leader, an individual seen in a picture behind the Brigade Leader was the parallel Earth's version of the Doctor.*" Do you know a source for the "it was later confirmed"?

Comment: The target novelization of the story is one source.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Never mind, found it. Added - and thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly the masks worn by Faction Paradox in the 8th doctor novelisations were made from the skulls of vampire Time Lords from an alternate reality where the Great Vampires won (mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faction_Paradox#Overview).